# Object() vs. Function()

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, constructor, prototype

It is my understanding that pretty much everything in JS is an object and that constructors are one way to make a new object. I know that data types like Array, Function, and Objects all have to use the new keyword, thereby making them objects and on the backend works like `new Array()`, `new Function()` or `new Object()` Please correct me if I am wrong. This is where things got confusing for me. I assigned x to an array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. When I inspected x, it showed that the `[[prototype]]` is an Array and the constructor is the `Array()` object. At the end, it showed the `Array()` object's prototype which is Object and the constructor for the Object to be `Object()`. I understood everything until I typed in `Object.constructor` and the result was `Function()`. Shouldn't it be `Object()`, instead of `Function()`? If the constructor of an object is `new Object()`, why is it telling me that Function is the constructor? That way if I create a new object it will be instantiated like this: `let x = new Function()`, yes? That was not the only one. Every primitive and reference data type gave the same result. Here is the code. I was so happy when I thought I grasped this knowledge and then I somehow I broke it. Hmmm, much like coding....lol. Thanks in advance for explaining.

```
let x = [1, 2, 3, 4];

undefined

x;

(4) [1, 2, 3, 4]

   0: 1

   1: 2

   2: 3

   3: 4

length: 4

  **[[Prototype]]: Array(0)**

  at: ƒ at()

  concat: ƒ concat()

  **constructor: ƒ Array()**

  copyWithin: ƒ copyWithin()

  entries: ƒ entries()

  every: ƒ every()

  ...Many other Array methods...

  **[[Prototype]]: Object**

     **constructor: ƒ Object()**

     hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()

     isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()

     propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()

     toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()

    toString: ƒ toString()

    valueOf: ƒ valueOf()

    __defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()

    __defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()

    __lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()

    __lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()

    __proto__: (...)

    get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()

    set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()

**Array.constructor;**

*ƒ Function() { [native code] }*

**Object.constructor;**

*ƒ Function() { [native code] }*

**Function.constructor;**

*ƒ Function() { [native code] }*

**String.constructor;**

*ƒ Function() { [native code] }*

**Boolean.constructor;**

*ƒ Function() { [native code] }*

**Number.constructor;**

*ƒ Function() { [native code] }*
```

Comment: _"all have to use the new keyword"_ - no, because they can be created using literals. `[]` creates a new array without "new".

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is a function used to construct objects. Since it is a function, its own constructor is `Function`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could think this way, `constructor` is a function that return an instance of object.

Now why you add `new` is that so you create a new instance of the object.

Now class and function in js is almost the same.

Look below example

### object example

```js
class test {
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  getName(){
    return this.name;
  }
}


console.log(new test("hej").getName())
```

### Function Example

```js
function test(name){
  this.name = name;
}

test.prototype.getName =function(){
  return this.name;
}

console.log(new test("hej").getName())
```